# How could I optimize this formular

Tags: excel

I have a range of values between 2 columns: I need to check every row in colum A and in column B respectively and return the number of time if the condition is True

```
=SUM(IF(AND(I28=B8;J28=G15);1;0) + IF(AND(I29=B8;J29=G15);1;0)+ IF(AND(I30=B8;J30=G15);1;0) + IF(AND(I31=B8;J31=G15);1;0))
```

I used This function it's working. But I didn't find how to optimized if I am going to work for a lot of rows.

I tried this but it's not workig:

```
=SUM(IF(AND((I28:I31)=B8;(J28:J31)=G15);1;0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(I28:I31;B8;J28:J31;G15)
```